# How to connect dbml with the database?

Tags: database, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2012, sdf

Hi I am new to database concepts and database related programming. Now I want to create a local database in my application. I am using Visual studio 2012 for simple adesktop based application. I have created a local Database  "`PersonDatabase.sdf`"  and its shows in server explorer too. Now doing some Google I come to know that I need to create a `.dbml`file like `PersonDatabase.dbml` in my solution explorer.

I did add -> new items -> LINQ to SQL Classes and it's also showing in the solution explorer. But in the Object relational designer I can not drag and drop the already available databases. It shows `"the selected object(s) use an unsupported data provider  "`.

I Google it find that I need to create it manually using `sqlClient.exe` available in  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0` Tools in Windows 8 Pro with VS 2012. When I am inside the folder `"NETFX 4.0"` I run the following command "sqlMetal.exe PersonDatabase.sdf /dbml:PersonDatabase.dbml". But in the command prompt it says PersonDatabse.sdf doesnot exist. then I give the entire path but due to the space issue in "Visual Studio" it does not execute. Finally I did like this

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>SqlMetal
.exe @"C:\Users\kumar\Docs\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Junk\DBMLDatabaseConn
ection\DBMLDatabaseConnection\PersonDatabase.sdf" /dbml:@"C:\Users\kumar\Docs\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Junk\DBMLDatabaseConnection\DBMLDatabaseConnection\PersonDatabase.dbml"`

But it says that PersonDatabase.sdf doesnot exist. But it exist in that directory. I have gone thorugh few sites they also said that same procedure. Am I doing something wrong? Can this be done? One more question is what is the role of dbml to connect to sdf here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to do the same is slightly different Use following syntax :

```
SqlMetal /dbml:PersonDatabase.sdf PersonDatabase.dbml
```